# How to get month name from date in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

the goal is to get month name and year from previous month date. Such:  `October -2019`

But I got an error:

```
import datetime


d = datetime.date.today()
first_day = d.replace(day=1) # gives first day of current month
last_day = first_day - datetime.timedelta(days=1) # gives last date of previous month
print(last_day.strtime("%B"))
```

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x:\Documents\Python\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(last_day.strtime("%B"))
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'strtime'
```

Comment: The error message is correct. It appears you are looking for `strftime()` [note the "f"!]. The `%B` should be the correct format code.

Comment: Ooooh! Attention to details!!! Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper method to use is called `strftime`, not `strtime`